# Is it possible to control view direction with only the keyboard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to map mouse moves to the keyboard (e.g. Keypad 4 to look left and so on)?

I saw a skse script but I can't find it with Google.

Comment: Im not sure that's even possible.

Comment: @ProZantrex: Well, that's why he's asking. :P

Comment: It is possible anyone saw the skrim kinect video, controling the mouse with the upper body. I now control the mouse with my left hand but I need for the shield...

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) .

It remaps your keyboard/mouse to whatever you tell it to. You just have to make sure to run the program with your script prior to loading up Skyrim.

[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=26338922)